# Make Boolean not affected by subsurf modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have an object (1) with a part of it created using another object (2) and the Boolean modifier. Is there any way to make 1's subsurf modifier not effect the part of the mesh created by 2? In my case I have a mouth seperate from the head, and a boolean modifier so I dont have to modify it with shape keys. But the head seems to make the mouth smooth, even though I have creases on the mouth. I cannot remove the subsurf, the eyelids need it to be smooth, and are part of the head mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifiers are calculated from top to bottom in what is called a **[Stack](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/the_stack.html?highlight=stack)**.

Changing the order of the modifiers in the stack will yield different results:

Boolean before Subsurf:

[image]

Boolean after Subsurf:

[image]

Animating the size of the cube:

[image]

Comment: That worked, I did not know it was that simple! Thank you. I'd up vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Check back in a day or two, and you might have enough reputation to upvote the answer. In the meantime, unless I"m mistaken, you have enough reputation, @ZacPerry, to accept the answer.